# Как позвонить на мобильном с Javascript (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, мобильная-разработка

Пишу приложение для мобайл на HTML, Javascript. Как позвонить из такого приложения?

Comment: Думаю, есть смысл [сослаться на готовый ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers) этого вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="tel:+123456789"> Позвонить </a>
```